# PHP generator vs. regular loops

Tags: php, foreach, generator

I would like to know if it makes sense to use a generator in the following case (or if there is no significant difference between it and using an regular foreach):

I have some chunk of data from MariaDb (~200 rows) which I need to format. Usually I do it this way:

```
<?php
  //regular foreach
  $formated_data = [];    
  foreach ($db_data as $key => $value)
  {
    $formated_data[] = my_format_function($value);
  }
?>
```

PHP documentation states that

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over
> a set of data without needing to build an array in memory.

If I save the results from the generator inside an array (code bellow), wouldn't that be almost the same as using the regular foreach ?

```
<?php
// foreach inside generator
$my_array = [];
foreach (my_format_function2($data) as $key => $value) {
  $my_array[] = $value;
}

function my_format_function2($data)
{
  foreach($data as $key=>$value)
  {
    // some format data code, then:
    yield $formated_data;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: its no use in your case because you already have $db_data in memory, it would start working and be useful if you moved the db query and $db_data and all that good stuff into the generator so its just yields the row

Comment: additionally, array_map could replace that loop, also you already have $db_data, making $formated_data/$my_array is just doubling the memory any way, are you aware you can do foreach ($db_data as &$value)?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Lawrence. I understood that whenever I want to use the generator to improve memory usage I need to think about using it in the 'create/get data step', is that right? Doing something like:
function get_data(){ 
_  $pdo_sth->prepare($query);
_  yield $pdo_sth->fetch();
}
And then using the foreach, array map, etc. over it. Would that be the case, or that would only make several consults in my db?

obs.: I just found out about the foreach($db_data as $value) while searching for answer to this topic. And thanks for the tip about the array_map!